# Django's DateTimeField's "auto_now" doesn't seem to work

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Comment` model. It has following timestamp fields:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
last_edit = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now when I update a comment using this format: `Comment.objects.filter(...).update(text="some new text")`, the `last_edit` field doesn't get updated while the text of the comment does get updated. What's the issue?

Update: Also, I am using `filter` because `update` doesn't work with `get`, i.e.,  `Comment.objects.get(...).update(...)` won't work. What I actually want to do is `get` because I am sure only one comment has to updated at one time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're using `update`, which does the update directly in the database, whereas `auto_now` is done in Python. This would work:

```
for commment in Comment.objects.filter(...):
    comment.text="some new text"
    comment.save()
```

Obviously, this is less efficient than doing it in one go in the db. If you really need that, then you'd have to set the date in the update as well:

```
Comment.objects.filter(...).update(text="some new text", last_edit=datetime.datetime.now())
```